# The most effective/flexible implementation for tags

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am looking for a way to implement tags to basically any class/objects. It could be products, blog, user, comments,... My idea was to create an interface that I can implement to any classes. By doing so, it will automatically create everything needed in the DB.

Is there a way to do such thing ? or do I need to create an entity for each 'taggable' object ?

Comment: Please go research an approach to solve this. We can help you with problems from there. But this sounds "primarily opinion based".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create an EntityTag table in your Database?

You would also need an EntityType table too. For each POCO class object you declare an EntityTypeId :-

An example,

```
  new Blog
    {
      Id = 1,
      Name = "Blog 1"
    }

    new Blog
    {
      Id = 2,
      Name = "Blog 2"
    }

    new Product
    {
      Id = 1,
      Name = "Product"
    }

    new EntityType
    {
      Id = 1,
      EntityTypeName = "Blog"
    }

    new EntityType
    {
      Id = 2,
      EntityTypeName = "Product"
    }
```

When you want to create a tag against any object, you simply create a new Entity Tag entry in your Database like this :-

```
New EntityTag
{
  EntityId = 1,
  EntityTypeId = 1,
  Text = "blog test 1 tag"
};
```

This EntityTag would be associated to Blog Test 1.

```
New EntityTag
    {
      EntityId = 2,
      EntityTypeId = 1,
      Text = "blog test 2 tag"
    };
```

This EntityTag would be associated to Blog Test 2.

Finally,

```
 New EntityTag
    {
      EntityId = 1,
      EntityTypeId = 2,
      Text = "Product tag"
    };
```

You will need to implement methods for getting an Entity's type, but this is really easy. Bolt on an Interface as you suggested. You can create a partial class for each POCO object that inherits for your interface, in here you can set the EntityTypeName.

Hope this helps.